# Lookup one cell in another sheet then return corresponding value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets containing various columns in which two columns contains document number and prices. Now I want to match cell K3 (a document number ) of Sheet 1 within column D (all document numbers) of Sheet 2. If match exists, then i want the corresponding price mentioned in Column V to be returned.

This is the formula I've tried:

```
=VLOOKUP(K3,'Sheet1 (2)'!D2:D896,22,FALSE)
```

Comment: Any syntax or formula suggestion to solve this please.

Comment: [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) maybe?

Comment: I have tried my best using it but couldn’t get the sesired result

Comment: If value in K3 matches in D2:D896, then the value in column 22 must be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) documentation is helpful here, especially points 2 and 3 which correspond to parts 2 and 3 of the formula.

> 2. The range where the lookup value is located. Remember that the lookup value should always be in the first column in the range for VLOOKUP to work correctly. For example, if your lookup value is in cell C2 then your range should start with C.
> 3. The column number in the range that contains the return value. For example, if you specify B2: D11 as the range, you should count B as the first column, C as the second, and so on.

So change the second `D` to `V` in your lookup range, and change the column to `19` instead of `22` - `D` is the 1st column, `E` the second and so on till `V`, the 19th column of the lookup range.

```
=VLOOKUP(K3,'Sheet1 (2)'!D2:V896,19,FALSE)
```

if `VLOOKUP` is not your thing, consider `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

```
=INDEX('Sheet1 (2)'!V:V,MATCH(K3,'Sheet1 (2)'!D:D,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(K3,Sheet1!D3:E8,2,FALSE)
```

In formula second last argument is the column number of values.

[image: Sheet 1 having values against document no.]
[image: Sheet 2 get values against document no]